# Docker `docker-entrypoint-initdb` not getting linked

Tags: docker, init, alpine-linux, docker-volume

I'm trying to add an `init.sh` script to the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` so I can finish provisioning my DB in a docker container. The script is in a `scripts` directory in my local directory where the `Dockerfile` lives. The `Dockerfile` is simply:

```
FROM glats/alpine-lamp
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

The build command works and completes with no errors, and then when I try to run the container it also runs fine, with the linked volume with the init script:

```
docker run -d --name mydocker -p 8080:80 -it mydocker \
-v ~/Docker/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

However when I log into the running container, I don't see any `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, and obviously the `init.sh` never runs:

```
/ # ls /
bin       etc       media     proc      sbin      tmp
dev       home      mnt       root      srv       usr
entry.sh  lib       opt       run       sys       var
```

Does anyone know why the volume isn't getting mounted?

Comment: Docker options like `-v` need to be before the image name `mydocker`; anything after the image name is taken as the command to be run.  (It also looks like that image is ignoring the command it's given.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such logic defined in the Docker image that you are using, the [entrypoint](https://github.com/glats/alpine-lamp/blob/master/entry.sh) of the above image just starts MySQL and httpd and does not any ability to construct Database from entrypoint.

If you want to have the ability to run init script using [mysql-entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/d284e15821ac64b6eda1b146775bf4b6f4844077/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) and construct the database you need to use offical image.

**[Initializing a fresh instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)**

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions `.sh, .sql and .sql.gz` that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

Also running container, better to use one process per container. you can look into this [docker-compose](https://github.com/nanoninja/docker-nginx-php-mysql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file that runs the stack as per rule of container "one process per container"